# Error in having a sequence - TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, token

I need your help in joining a list of words into a string. I have tried to map it to a string but to no avail. Here is a snippet of my for-loop.

```
for i in range(len(tokenized)):
    tokenized[i] = ' '.join(tokenized[i])
```

This is what is stored in  tokenized

````
0                         [, halv, cancel, due]
1    [mercyofallah, good, time, wrap, granular, det...
2    [day, digit, india, murder, e, learn, g, onlin...
3    [india, like, run, remain, rna, kit, essenti, ...
4    [tough, time, best, way, grow, learn, case, te...
Name: clean_art, dtype: object```
````

Comment: Is `tokenized[i]` a list ? I think only then can you join it.

Comment: yes it is a list @Sajan

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do, not sure what datatype tokenized is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'tokenized': [
    ['mercyofallah', 'good', 'time', 'wrap', 'granular'],
    ['day', 'digit', 'india']
]
})
df['string'] = df['tokenized'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
print(df)



                                   tokenized                                string
0  [mercyofallah, good, time, wrap, granular]  mercyofallah good time wrap granular
1                         [day, digit, india]                       day digit india
```

Comment: this is how the data is like, strings.     Check up as i have included it in the question. Tried your solution but to no avail. @NYC Coder